# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called on Touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

My **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method not called. I reload table and its reloaded and also called all methods of **talbeView**

Here is my all methods of tableview :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *s = (NSString *) [app.Glb.arrayRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *cellIdentifire = @"CellRoomList";
    CellRoomList *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (CellRoomList*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellRoomList" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.lblRoomName.text = s;

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [app.Glb.arrayRoomList count];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *userName = (NSString *) [app.Glb.arrayRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"userName :---- %@",userName);
    ViewController *chatController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    chatController.chatWithUser = userName;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatController animated:YES];
}
```

I read some questions in stack but can't get answers.

and if i long touch to cell than it cell's color change but not called `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Why its not called ?

Here is Snap :

[image]

Comment: Have you set tableView delegate with your viewController, `tableView.delegate = self;`

Comment: yes i added it on XIB, that's why my other methods called

Comment: Are you able to check user name as you are printing it in NSLog ?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is tableView delegate . cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection tableview datasource.So you said both are connected. Check once this the issue with delegate. Remove once and again add try it

Comment: yes it is same ... @Vickyexpert

Comment: yes @Pavankumar i connected both in table.

Comment: @Kabali then it means your method is calling but not redirecting to next screen as you have initiate view controller in wrong manner so change it and you will be able to redirect

Comment: commenting viewcontroller navigation not working ...

Comment: now check my answer

Comment: @Kabali - check once your tableviewcell Clickable Area

Comment: is your view controller embeded with navigation controller? @Kabali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced this general issue so many times.

Please take care of following things

1. Make sure your cell dont have any type of touch/tap gestures to its contents
2. Make sure your view dont have any touch/tap gestures applied
3. Make sure you dont have any View or Table view categories(extension) that has any touch/tap gestures applied [This is more critical as we don`t expect this usually]
4. Check if you have any third party who works for touch/tap gestures

The most common reasons are gestures on view that prevent the table to get touches on cell.

Comment: yes thx that's the prob, im adding gesture to dismiss keyboard on view tap, that making prob here.

Answer (score 2):

There might be other views in cell that could intercepting the touch events. Make sure to set **NO** to the property **userInteractionEnabled** for views.

Comment: Disable for views(UILabel..) in your custom cell and check the table row selection.

Answer (score 0):

As you told you are getting user name, it means your method is calling but not redirecting to another screen, as you have initiate view controller in wrong manner so change it by below,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   NSString *userName = (NSString *) [app.Glb.arrayRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"userName :---- %@",userName);

   ViewController *chatController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerId" bundle:nil];

   chatController.chatWithUser = userName;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: it called on long press .

Comment: It will call on click only, as we have implement logic inside didselect method not in gesture like log pressed, may be first time it take sometimes but it should only work on touch any row

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check if selection is set to single selection!